# gRPC stream interceptor not passing context to request method

Tags: go, grpc

I have the following gRPC interceptor running serverside, which wraps a serverstream and passes it on to the next handler:

```golang
// HarmonyContext contains a custom context for passing data from middleware to handlers
type HarmonyContext struct {
    context.Context
    Request interface{}
    UserID  uint64
    Limiter *rate.Limiter
}

type IHarmonyWrappedServerStream interface {
    GetWrappedContext() HarmonyContext
}

type HarmonyWrappedServerStream struct {
    grpc.ServerStream
    WrappedContext HarmonyContext
}

func (ss HarmonyWrappedServerStream) GetWrappedContext() HarmonyContext {
    return ss.WrappedContext
}

func (m Middlewares) HarmonyContextInterceptorStream(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    wrapped := WrapServerStream(ss)
    return handler(srv, wrapped)
}

func WrapServerStream(stream grpc.ServerStream) HarmonyWrappedServerStream {
    if existing, ok := stream.(HarmonyWrappedServerStream); ok {
        return existing
    }
    return HarmonyWrappedServerStream{ServerStream: stream, WrappedContext: HarmonyContext{
        Context: stream.Context(),
    }}
}
```

and in the handler itself, I have the following code:

```golang
func (v1 *V1) StreamGuildEvents(r *corev1.StreamGuildEventsRequest, s corev1.CoreService_StreamGuildEventsServer) error {
    wrappedStream := s.(middleware.IHarmonyWrappedServerStream)
    println(wrappedStream)
    return nil
}
```

However, I get the following runtime error when sending a streaming request:
`interface conversion: *corev1.coreServiceStreamGuildEventsServer is not middleware.IHarmonyWrappedServerStream: missing method GetWrappedContext`
In fact, the ServerStream in the handler is completely different from the one in the interceptors. Is there any way to make the interceptor pass the custom ServerStream properly?

Comment: The service handler doesn't need to make the type assertion. The interceptor should be transparent to the handler. Also see the interceptor examples here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/interceptor

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The reason I want to make an assertion is to be able to pass context/data between the stream interceptor and the handler itself. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Overriding the methods of https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc?tab=doc#ClientStream would be a good way to pass/modify data. The context() can be used for wrapping the parent context.

Comment: as seen in the code I provided for the question, I have already done that. I wrapped the ServerStream struct in an interceptor, and have overridden the context. But when testing, the handler's stream parameter doesn't seem to have been passed from the interceptor.

Comment: The provided code snippet only embeds `grpc.ServerStream`, but doesn't override the `Context()` method. Try implementing the method to override it.

Answer (score 1):

We've opened up one of our repos to demonstrate this if it helps anybody.

https://github.com/drud/api-common/blob/main/interceptors/state.go#L207

Very similar to @Bluskript impl however I do not have the same issue encountered above.  I believe this might be from the return type `grpc.StreamServerInterceptor` and where I am using the context getter.